# What's the best method for responsively displaying 2 columns in reverse order?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Consider the following example for a 2-column layout:

```
<div id="leftColumn" class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Some content</p>
</div>
<div id="rightColumn" class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

What is the best method for displaying #rightColumn above #leftColumn on mobile breakpoints? One solution is to create extra markup and hide the extra section at desired breakpoints. But that doesn't seem very semantic.

Is there a better way?

Comment: why not start the content the other way round?

Comment: That's certainly an option. But what if it's not?

Comment: If it's meant to go before in mobile, then surely the page order should be that the content in the right starts before the left if you had no styling?  Anyway I would do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/5VHe9/) as it is easier to change left and right than it is to change top and bottom

Comment: "That's certainly an option. But what if it's not?" If you have access to JavaScript, it's an option. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap3 is mobile first, so ideally the markup should be mobile first. I'd swap the `<div>`s around then use `-push` and -`pull` from the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) to move the the divs left and right on larger screens.

Basically `push-` and `pull-` does exactly what it says on the tin. They push columns (to the right), and pull them (to the left). I could go on an explain how it works, but I think it's a little out the scope of this answer. There's a terrific article on the magic behind bootstrap's grid over at [helloerik.com](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works), which also includes a detailed section on Bootstraps `push-` and `pull-` classes.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much the answer I was looking for, however it might be helpful to describe why push and pull work. If you wouldn't mind, I'll go ahead and accept this as the answer afterwards.

Comment: How's that? The link does a far better job of explaining the effect the classes have than I could.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the easiest way is to change the DOM structure.

HTML:

```
<div id="rightColumn" class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Some content</p>
</div>

<div id="leftColumn" class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #rightColumn, #leftColumn {
    width: 50%;
    /* other definitions */
    float: left;
   }
   #rightColumn {
    float: right;
   }
   @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #rightColumn, #leftColumn { float: none; }
   }
```